# Loop is not working in a "no number confirmation" javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop, conditional-statements, nan, boolean-expression

Explorer ignore the loop in my code and do nothing with var id. I'm really confused about it as far as i check it should tell me when there is a number and when not.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
    <body>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    <!--
        var c;
        var id;
        var x=prompt("let´s see if this work.");
        c =(x.length);
        alert("have " + c + " characters ");
        alert("Last character is " + x.substring((c-1), c));

        // loop supposed to  check ever character and stop when counter "c" reach 0.
        //id is supposed to become false if there is a number inside and stop the loop
        // for some reason firefox is skipping loop
        while (c!=0 && id===true)
        {
            alert("start in " + c);
            id=isNaN(x.substring((c-1), c));
            c=(c-1);
            alert("ends in " + c);
        }
        // id true mean no nomber id false mean there is a number
        if (id === true)
        {
            alert("No number inside")
        }
        else
        {
            alert("number inside");
        }
    </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: where is id assigned a value?

Comment: your while loop is being skipped because you haven't set `id` to true.

Answer (score 1):

When you come to this line

```
while(c!=0 && id===true)
```

`id` is `undefined`. So the loop never starts.

Supposing the rest of the code is correct, a solution might be to change the condition to

```
while(c!=0 && id!==false)
```

---

As an aside, even if you should fix your code and understand why it doesn't currently work, note that there are simpler solutions to test if a string contains a digit, for example [regular expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp) :

```
var hasDigit = /\d/.test(x);
```

Comment: Arg ! You were faster than me :)